# Visual Studio 2013 connect sqlserver error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

when I connect sqlserver2013 with vs2013 .net4.0 ,I got the error message:
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Are you using C++? Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

We just found that this is the problem of Visual Studio 2013.

"Attempted to read or write protected memory" exception occurs in dubugging mode.

You can switch to VS 2012 or 2010 while waiting for an update.